# CollectionView scrollToItem does not scroll

Tags: ios, collectionview

I have a horizontal collection view and a button. When button i tapped I call

```
let indexPath : IndexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
```

the problem is that animation of scrolling doesnt happen but if I make a breakpoint on `scrollToItem` it enters inside method.

Why does it happen ?

Comment: did you try to run this on main thread?

Comment: Check whther indexPath is proper or not?

Comment: Retry by `disable` the breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

try that code..

```
collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(
        NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: startIndex),
        atScrollPosition: .None,
        animated: false)
 }
```

Comment: if and. is right then make it right for click on right. so other consideration is you getting your and as per your require.